# A comment in the Disquisitiones Arithmeticae

Tags: number-theory

Gauss proves that if $t\equiv\pm 3\mod 8$, then $2$ is a non-(quadratic)-residue modulo $t$ as follows:

> Assume $t\equiv\pm 3\mod 8$ is the smallest counter-example, and say $a^2\equiv 2\mod t$, that is $a^2=2+tu$, where $a<t$. By taking $t-a$ instead of $a$ if necessary, we can assume $a$ is odd (since $t$ is odd, so $a$ and $t-a$ can't both be even). Since $a$ is odd, $a^2\equiv 1\mod 8$. So modulo $8$, we have $1\equiv 2\pm3u$ which implies $u\equiv\mp3$. But from $a^2=2+tu$ we conclude that $2$ is a residue modulo $u$, and recalling that $a<t$ we conclude that $u<t$, so $u$ is a smaller counterexample than $t$, which was assumed minimal.

He then says that even if we assumed $a$ even, we could do the same proof, we would just have to distinguish between the cases $a\equiv0$ and $a\equiv2$ modulo $4$.

I don't see it. If say we assume $a$ is a multiple of $4$, then $a^2\equiv 0$ modulo $8$, which, imitating the above, gives us $u\equiv\pm 2$ modulo $8$, and so we don't get a contradiction.